# Drawable resource not displaying with button

Tags: android, button, drawable

I'm trying to follow the tutorial located at http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/, however I'm not getting the expected result. Everything compiles fine, however when I run it I get a button without any colors, gradients, or even borders (so actually all I see is just the button text). The button itself responds to events ok.

In order to be compatible with as many devices as possible I'm using android:minSdkVersion="3", could this be an issue?

This is part of my layout xml file:

```
 <TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_calculate"
        android:background="@drawable/copy_btn"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:padding="5dp" />
 </TableRow>
```

This is copy_btn.xml, located inside drawables.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" >
         <shape>
             <solid
                 android:color="#70c656" />
             <stroke
                 android:width="1dp"
                 android:color="#53933f" />
             <corners
                 android:radius="3dp" />
             <padding
                 android:left="10dp"
                 android:top="10dp"
                 android:right="10dp"
                 android:bottom="10dp" />
         </shape>
     </item>
     <item>
         <shape>
             <gradient
                 android:startColor="#70c656"
                 android:endColor="#53933f"
                 android:angle="270" />
             <stroke
                 android:width="1dp"
                 android:color="#53933f" />
             <corners
                 android:radius="4dp" />
             <padding
                 android:left="10dp"
                 android:top="10dp"
                 android:right="10dp"
                 android:bottom="10dp" />
         </shape>
     </item>
 </selector>
```

Thanks

Comment: Add android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" to your button.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the same result as before. Any other suggestions??. My new xml (partial) is       <TableRow>
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button_calculate"
              android:background="@drawable/copy_btn"
              android:layout_column="1"
              android:layout_span="2"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp" />
      </TableRow>

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if u add android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" to your button in Android Manifest. minSdkVersion has to do nothing with this as most of the times they are backward compatable.

What "(so actually all I see is just the button text)" means? How can u see a button text when u haven't used android:text attribute? Either there is another button in ur app or u r setting text from code. Do check this.

Comment: Actually I set the text in code. This suggestion doesn't work. I'm getting the same result as before. Any other suggestions?? My new xml (partial) is:       <TableRow>
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button_calculate"
              android:background="@drawable/copy_btn"
              android:layout_column="1"
              android:layout_span="2"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp" />
      </TableRow>

Comment: Remove tag android:layout_span="2" or just set its value to "1".